# What are the good fstab options for a RAID 0 SSD home partition?

Tags: raid, home-directory

I followed this guide for RAID setup : [RAID guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Did this guide  for the migration [Ubunutu guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)

Since everything is sorted out I just need to know the `/etc/fstab/` parameters recommended for this.

This is my fstab but I want to confirm this are good settings

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=e27c04ad-ec57-4b6d-8bcd-c7613c271cf2 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
#UUID=3128be42-d242-1a08-afba-a2a3b7c965dc /home           ext4   defaults           0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Your fstab entry for /swapfile should be `/swapfile                       none            swap    sw              0       0`

Comment: Sorry didn't copy the text well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain the fields of `fstab` entries.

The first field describes *which* block device, remote file system or similar to mount. Today, it's commonly referenced by UUID for block devices, but other, valid alternatives is `LABEL` or simply the old fashioned `/dev/sdb1`.

The second field describes the mount point. This describes where you want the file system accessible to the system. For a home file system, `/home` will do just nice.

The third field describes file system type. Common file systems are `ext4`, `exfat`, `ext3`, `xfs` and many more. This should match the on disk format.

The fourth field is options. The options are partially standardized, and partially file system dependent, as different file systems supports different options. Commonly we'll see `defaults` in this field. `defaults` is the... default option, implying `rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, async`. The meaning of each of those is as follows

- `rw`

  - Mount the file system in read write mode.
- `suid`

  - Allow setuid binaries. This may not be a good idea for `/home` on a shared server, as it could make privilege escalation simpler. On `/home` `nosuid` may make sense. On `/` and `/usr/`, `nosuid` will result in a non-functioning system.
- `dev`

  - Allow device files on the file system. Again, does not make sense for `/home`, and may aid in privilege escalation. No harm from having `nodev` set on a home partition.
- `exec`

  - Allow execution of binaries on this file system. This is probably a good feature on `/home`, but disabling it may improve security in multi user scenarios, as users will not be able to run software from `/home`.
- `auto`

  - Mount automatically during boot, and with `mount -a`
- `nouser`

  - Users cannot mount or umount the file system. Only root can. Sensible for all system partitions, such as `/home`.
- `async`

  - Mount in asynchronous mode. This basically means that data can be reported back as written, without actually being written to physical disks. Greatly improves performance, at the cost of data integrity. A trade off the user has to make.

The fifth field describes which file systems should be dumped. `dump` is generally a ancient backup tool, and not really relevant today. Leave to zero.

The sixth field describes the fsck order. `/` should be 1, which will be checked first. Any other file system should be `2` (or higher), to be checked after `/`.

For the options field, there's a lot of relevant options. I've covered what `defaults` means above, and as you see, you probably don't *need* `dev` or `suid` for a `/home` partition. In a multiuser setup, you **probably** want to disable it.

There's no right or wrong either when it comes to the correct mount options. Different people do different trade offs. On a personal laptop, not having `exec` on `/home` may be a annoyance. At a shared web server, it may be an valuable part of the security.

Comment: Will the options "auto,rw,nouser" work fine for the home partition?

Comment: You probably want `exec` and `async` as well. This may be done with `defaults,nodev,nosuid`